# upload & download large file over internet

Tags: web-services, architecture, file-transfer

I have a requirement where I need to upload a large file (can be 10 GB) to  a shared space(windows) ( say APP1) . and we have a separate application( say APP2) different network now  I need to download the same file from in second application via internet.

My approach is I need to create webservice to upload the document to shared space. and then expose a webservice for outer world to download the document.

My point is how I can manage the huge files upload/download through webservice ?
Please suggest if some one have any idea. I have flexibikity to use any third party APIs.**but the application can talk only through webservices.**

Comment: What is your definition of 'web service'?

Comment: web service means normal SOAP web services...

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not really clear which development platform you mean, .NET, Java, etc.
Also it's important to know how interoperable your services should be, security requirements, etc. Anyway will try to come up with a couple of solutions which you might research in more detail if you found them useful.

**.NET**
It's relatively easy to built such a web service with WCF. It supports streaming which could be interoperable, reliable and secure to some extend. You can read more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This approach implies you have a huge disk to store files and you have a good recovery plan for that in case it goes down or just dies.

**.NET, Java, etc. - cloud based**

There are a lot of vendors who provide cloud storage and APIs to work with it. It's an ideal solution for a quick start. They take care of data availability, redundancy, etc. All you have to do is to use their API to upload and download files and to pay them for this :) In many cases it's worth it. Personally I used to work with Amazon S3. Their API is simple to use and there's plenty of docs for that.

**EDIT:**

> Amazon S3 provides a simple web-services interface that can be used to
>   store and retrieve any amount of data, at any time, from anywhere on
>   the web.

I think you should take a look at Amazon S3 overview [here](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).
This also provides API for a number of different platforms - Java, .NET, Node.js, etc. You an find the full list [here](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Maksym, I am working on java...the way you suggest but our client may use .Net to download the file. as my understanding Amazon S3 will provide a server where they will stage the file and we can request the file by there API..is it possible to use webservice communication with Amazon S3 server to download and upload the files.?